# Счетчик для массива в БД

Tags: база-данных, json, счетчики

Всем привет!
Может кто-нибудь сказать как правильно писать счетчик для внесения массива в БД?
Пробовал десятки вариантов - не получается!
Суть: внутри массива $array (это марка) будет ключ ['models'] - а в нем по порядку, начиная с [1] внесены разные модели машин.

if($target=="add_model"){

```
$i=1;<br>
```

// разная инфо про $@_POST;

```
$far=array('model_name'=>$mod_name, 'opisanie'=>$opisanie);<br>

$array = array('ааа'=>$asd);<br>

$array['models']['$i++']=$far; // счетчик некорректно записан!<br>
$json=(json_encode($array));<br>

$sql = "UPDATE marki SET json='$json' WHERE id=$marka_id";<br>
$res = mysqli_query($connect,$sql);<br>

    echo "<script>window.location='index.php'</script>";<br>
```

}
?>

Comment: Если $array['models'] есть массив, может его тогда обьявить? $array['models']=array() ?  И причём тут база, если идёт нумерация в массиве?

Comment: `['$i++']` ну ++ точно никогда не выполнится он же внутри кавычек, зачем они вообще, напишите просто `[$i++]`

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Mike!
 
Правильный дали совет!
 
Получилось так:

$asd['models'][$i++]=$far;
 
$json=normJsonStr(json_encode($asd));
 
... 
$res=mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
 
$get=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);  
 
$sql = "UPDATE marki SET json='$json' WHERE id=$marka_id";
 
Ввод в БД (поле json) получился так как надо:
 
{"marka_name":"ИНФИНИТИ","models":{"1":{"model_name":"Айбек","opisanie":"Это я","marka_id":"55","photo":"aibek.jpg"}}}
 

?>